# stylesheet_link_tag and javascript_include_tag create tags without digest in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4

My env is

- rails (4.0.0)
- ruby 2.0.0p247

and using nginx and unicorn.

I have the following code in app/views/layout/application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

they create html tags without digest.

```
<link href="/assets/application.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/assets/application.js"></script>
```

I do assets:precompile like this.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

It create css and js with digest.

```
application-9746528cde7f7180a473328fd274c2ce.js
application-c0773e3ecaf5e09f2eef46885eebefe1.css
```

so my Rails application can't load css and js.

of course, I can access to http://example.com/assets/application-c0773e3ecaf5e09f2eef46885eebefe1.css

the following is my config/environments/production.rb

```
Myapp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
  config.log_level = :info
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

Is there any mistake in my configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The way to start unicorn is wrong.
I forgot to set RAILS_ENV when I start unicorn like that.

```
$ unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -D
```

however the right way it the following

```
$ unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -D -E production
```

thanks

Comment: Nice job figuring that out. Can you accept your own answer to mark this question as answered?